# ffmpeg only processes first image

Tags: image-processing, ffmpeg

I have a directory of .png images (I had previously tried .jpg until I read somewhere ffmpeg prefers .png).

The images share a file numbering format cof000.png - cof358.png.

I want to convert those images into a moving picture format. MPG or MP4 will be fine.

The command I have tried is

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 25 -i cof%03d.png -r 6 output.mp4
```

I adapted the command from this post, here:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53778503/ffmpeg-video-slideshow-only-takes-first-image
```

Even after trying numerous different permutations of the command the final file only has the first image in it. I am using windows.

What ffmpeg command do I need to use on Windows to compile all 180 image files into a single moving image?

Here is the output from using the command:

```
$ ffmpeg.exe -framerate 25 -i cof%03d.png -r 6 output.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200621
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enabl
e-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enabl
e-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --
enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-l
ibvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom
--enable-libgsm --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11
va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from 'cof%03d.png':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 1200x1200 [SAR 2834:2834 DAR 1:1], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] 264 - core 160 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264
.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_rang
e=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 s
liced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=
0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=6 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbt
ree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv444p, 1200x1200 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 6 fps, 12288
tbn, 6 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=23.0 Lsize=      26kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=2662518.5kbits/s speed=0.000541x
video:26kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.137195%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.42  size: 25465
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] mb I  I16..4:  2.1% 85.2% 12.7%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] 8x8 transform intra:85.2%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] coded y,u,v intra: 9.1% 0.9% 1.0%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 42% 39% 19%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 36% 11% 52%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 39% 17% 13%  5%  4%  6%  6%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 000001f7da6985c0] kb/s:1222.32
```

Comment: The numbering needs to be without gaps, so 000,001,002...

Comment: Here is the [documentation for the image2 demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-image2-1) it is responsible for making your image sequence a video. You might get useful info from there. You can force it's use and input options with `-f image2

Comment: Thank you both. Thank you Gyan, you are very observant to see that in my question. I hadn't even thought of it. You're right too! I rewrote my script so the numbering is sequential and it worked. Thanks! If you like put your answer in the main thread and I will accept it.